# is there a way to select $(this).("element")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

i have a parent class called post and it has certain styles depending on the type of post. example:

CSS

```
/*CSS*/
li.post.quote {/*STYLE*/}
li.post.photo {/*STYLE*/}
```

HTML

```
<!--HTML-->
<li class="post quote">
    <div class="someClass"> <!-- needs to be selected, but not by its class -->
</li>
<li class="post photo">
    <div class="someOtherClass"> <!-- needs to be selected, but not by its class -->
</li>
```

how would i select "needs to be selected" for each type of post without creating seperate functions for each type of post in jQuery?

**UPDATE:**
its going to be a hover animation, so i need it to only select only the "needs to be selected" of the post that is being hovered over.

Comment: You cannot have spaces in a class name otherwise it will look like individual class names per word.

Comment: @Jacob: I'm pretty sure the intent is 2 different classes. Or did you mean for the `<div>`? Guessing that's filler. :o)

Comment: It probably makes more sense to answerers if you give actual class names, then use code comments to provide additional information like "needs to be selected".

Comment: @Jacob the name "needs to be selected" is just for example, i am aware that spaces indicate different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking:

To get the div for all types of post:

```
$('.post > div');
```

To get the div for a particular type of post:

```
$('.post.quote > div');
```

---

Right, you mean on hover:

```
$('.post').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('div').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Or, `hover` can take two functions, one for enter, the other for leave:

```
$('.post').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('div').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).children('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: +1 I think this gets the point. Selecting the `<div>` in spite of its class.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just as simple as this:-

```
$(".post div.'needs to be selected'").<whatever>
```

or even

```
$(".post > div.'needs to be selected'").<whatever>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".post").find(".needs to be selected").select()` ?

Comment: its going to be a hover animation, so i need it to only select only the "needs to be selected" of the post that is being hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I don't understand what you mean, but can't you do $('li.post div.needs_to_be_selected')

Note that you're creating 4 classes on your div there: needs, to, be, and selected.